# Elasticsearch Error 56

Tags: elasticsearch

I finaly switched from Ubuntu to MacOS High Sierra and I am running into a problem.

I have installed Elasticsearch localy and I am getting a response.

Unfortunately I am getting the following error when executing bin/console fos:elastica:populate

[2018-08-15 08:07:53] elastica.ERROR: Elastica Request Failure {"exception":"[object] (Elastica\Exception\Connection\HttpException(code: 0): Unknown error:56 at /srv/www/litedesk/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Transport/Http.php:180)","request":{"path":"_bulk","method":"POST","data":"{\"index\":{\"_index\":\"******\",\"_type\":\"******\",\"_id\":\"1\"}}\n{\"name\":\"*******\",\"shortcut\":\"**\"}\n{\"index\":{\"_index\":\"*******\",\"_type\":\"*********\",\"_id\":\"2\"}}\n{\"name\":\"********\",\"shortcut\":\"****\"}\n{\"index\":{\"_index\":\"******\",\"_type\":\"*****\",\"_id\":\"3\"}}\n{\"name\":\"*****\",\"shortcut\":\"**\"}\n{\"index\":{\"_index\":\"********\",\"_type\":\"*********\",\"_id\":\"4\"}}\n{\"name\":\"******\",\"shortcut\":\"****\"}\n","query":[],"connection":{"config":{"headers":[]},"host":"localhost","port":9200,"logger":"fos_elastica.logger","compression":false,"retryOnConflict":0,"enabled":false}},"retry":false}

[Elastica\Exception\Connection\HttpException]
  Unknown error:56

The Elastic settings in my Symfony Project are

fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }

Thank you in advance
Best regards, Andrea

Answer (score 0):

It was simply the http.port which I had to set to 9200 in the elasticsearch.yml - That's it! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Config the port you wish to run the elasticsearch in **elasticsearch.yml**